# GOPATH error in windows "GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "

Tags: go

I am new to GO and getting an error when initializing GOPATH in windows. 
In my project folder is

C:\Users\kamin\Documents\pm-manager

and i am try to set path in environment variable (GOPATH)but it is getting an error 
go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: ":/cygdrive/c/Users/kamin/Documents/pm-manager\r\r".
Run 'go help gopath' for usage.

Comment: Apparently you're using Cygwin, which you didn't mention anywhere in your question. Why not just run `go` from a regular Windows `cmd` window?

Comment: @Michael i used Cygwin for build .sh file in a project

Comment: Go under cygwin works perfectly fine all you have to remember is one thing: If you use a Windows Go installation it expects a Windows GOPATH which means: 1: No ':' to separate entries (I think it's ';' on Win) and 2: Use Windows paths like `c:\User\kamin`. That's all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ran into same problem. Fix is quite simple: just specify the drive in front of the entire path name. The issue occurred because I was following the instructions on Go "Getting Started" page and set `GOPATH=%HOMEPATH%\Work` . The problem was that `%HOMEPATH%` was defined as a relative path (`\Users\MyName`), and so `GOPATH` now pointed to `\Users\MyName\Work` . All I needed to do was set `GOPATH=c:\Users\MyName\Work` and the error goes away.

Comment: @sandun-tharaka if the solution resolved your issue please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: extra note: If GOPATH is set in cygwin (in .bashrc) then change "\" to "/"

Comment: In Linux,  I tried `export GOPATH=$/media/storage/gocode` and got this error. I needed to remove dollar sign. It needs absolute path. So I did `export GOPATH=/media/storage/gocode` and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem. My go version is **go1.9.1 windows/amd64**.
However I fixed the problem by deleting the simucolon end of the GOPATH.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As alternative you can set it to %USERPROFILE%\ under Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

you can put this case uses cygwin this go path

export GOPATH='c:\folder\folder\folder\'

for cygwin is necessary in string 'c:\path'

normaly you try use /cygdrive/.../...

but for GO is not possible ( need c:\ or other drive )

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more error case that I experienced, was a silly-silly mistake in setting the GOPATH.

I added : `D\Go` (Forgot to added the colons after Drive letter).
Correct should have been `D:\Go`, Offcourse this resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this problem:

When you set the GOPATH in windows via commandline:

Remember to insert single quote on export path:

- Instead of: `export GOPATH=C:\<Your Go Path>`
  Use this: `export GOPATH='C:\<Your Go Path>'`
- Using double quotes will not work as it will format incorrectly: `export GOPATH="C:\<Your Go Path>"`