# Gopath environment errors

Tags: windows, go, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio code to write some go code. Everything was working fine yesterday, but now I can't run the debugger or build in VS-Code.

I am on Windows 10, and I use Powershell as my terminal of choice.

I get the following error:

```
go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "/Users/efronlicht/go".
For more details see: 'go help gopath'
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1
```

This is a VS-CODE specific error, because I can build go source files with `go build` through the terminal as usual.

Here are the results of `go env`:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\work\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
```

As you can see, my GOPATH is an absolute path, not a relative one.

Comment: Open your VS code settings, look for `go.gopath` in workspace settings and user settings. What is the value you have?

Comment: `"go.gopath": null`
I tried changing it to `"C:/work/go"` but that isn't doing it either.

Comment: Okay that's the default value in workspace. Let's try setting go.gopath in the user settings like `"go.gopath": "C:/work/go"`.

Comment: I did. No dice, unfortunately.

Comment: If that's case. Can you remove the `go.gopath` settings from VS code and close it. Also unset the GOPATH env variable.  Now we are gonna try with default values. VS Code and Go should use default gopath i.e. USER_HOME/go. If this doesn't work, sorry your VS code app is messed up. Do a clean install, try, try, again.

Comment: "*Everything was fine yesterday...*". So, did you updated any of Visual Studio Code or Go Extension that may causing this issue? Or maybe you set `GOPATH` in `env` as `%HOMEPATH%\...` ? Take a look at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884965/gopath-error-in-windows-gopath-entry-is-relative-must-be-absolute-path).

Comment: Nope. I tried a clean install and everything...

Comment: If you want we can create a chat and give it try on debugging your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on the clock right now so it will have to wait, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Powershell does not matter here: you only need for your tasks/launch.json to have the right value for GOPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use VSCode 1.13.1 on Windows 10, and I launch or debug without any issue.

Launching involves in your workspace a `${workspaceroot}/.vscode/tasks.json` file.
To be sure of the GOPATH value, mine includes:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "build",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "GOROOT": "D:/prgs/go/latest",
                    "GOPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"
                }
            },
            "echoCommand": false,
            "taskName": "install",
            "isBuildCommand": true
        },
```

You can replace `"${workspaceRoot}"` by `C:/work/go` in your case.
That way, a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> triggers a compilation+installation (`go install`)

And the debugger involves:

- having a `dlv.exe` in the %PATH%
- a `${workspaceroot}/.vscode/launch.json` file

Here is mine

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {
                "GOPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            "args": [],
            "showLog": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Again you can replace `"${workspaceRoot}"` by `C:/work/go` in your case (both in `GOPATH` and `cwd`).

Note that I specificy GOPATH *as well as* cwd (current working directory)
I open my file relative from the workspace root (that way, the breakpoints are recognized). A simple <kbd>F5</kbd> from `main.go` does run delve successfully (on Windows!)

With that, I can launch VSCode from a `cmd` Windows shell which has no `GOROOT` or `GOPATH` set, and it still works. (because my local user settings do include `"go.goroot": "D:/prgs/go/latest"`)

Comment: This did it! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @EfronLicht Well done! I recently switched to VSCode for Go, and I have a surprisingly good experience with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching VSCode from the command line in a tmux shell, try launching outside of tmux. Also try launching from the launcher. Changes in tmux and VSCode on MacOS have been giving me headaches with environment settings lately resulting in similar issues.

Comment: I don't know what tmux is, so that can't be it, sorry. Thank you for your advice!