# configuring golang gopath setup

Tags: go

When I run my `cat .bash_profile` command via terminal the following message is displayed:

> export GOPATH=c:/Users/Petey/Documents/go

I `cd` into the above, create a `main.go` and attempt to execute with `go run main.go`, but I receive this error. What am I doing incorrectly?

> go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "c".

Comment: Which terminal are you using ? according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884965/gopath-error-in-windows-gopath-entry-is-relative-must-be-absolute-path), it should be `c:\Users\Petey\ ` instead of `c:/Users/Petey/`

Comment: and don't forget to enclose with single quote (e.g `export GOPATH='C:\Users\Petey'`).

Comment: Peters-MacBook-Air:go Petey$ cat .bash_profile
export GOPATH=c:\Users\Petey\Documents\go this is my bash profile pwd however, when I run a go file still the same error of path must be relative.

Comment: once you have a working GOPATH you may want its children dirs  :   pkg, src, bin   as per  https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: @NewCoder are you using MacBook? please write your OS.

Comment: Yes I am using Macbook.

Comment: So to be clear, you're *not* using Microsoft Windows but macOS? In that case I don't quite follow why you're using a Windows path starting with a drive letter? Also, since Go 1.8 the GOPATH is automatically set to `$HOME/go`, so you may not need to set it yourself at all!

Answer (score 1):

You should quote the path like so:
export GOPATH="C:/Users/Petey/Documents/go"

Since it is Windows bash, you could also try:
export GOPATH="/mnt/c/Users/Petey/Documents/go"