# Error installing golang setup tools in visual studio code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with installing golang setup tools in visual studio code.

Also i have set paths like GOPATH and GOROOT ==>

[image]

```
Installing github.com/mdempsky/gocode FAILED
Installing github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs FAILED
Installing github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline FAILED
Installing github.com/acroca/go-symbols FAILED
Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru FAILED
Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename FAILED
Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv FAILED
Installing github.com/stamblerre/gocode FAILED
Installing github.com/rogpeppe/godef FAILED
Installing github.com/sqs/goreturns FAILED
Installing golang.org/x/lint/golint FAILED
Installing github.com/cweill/gotests/... FAILED
Installing github.com/fatih/gomodifytags FAILED
Installing github.com/josharian/impl FAILED
Installing github.com/davidrjenni/reftools/cmd/fillstruct FAILED
Installing github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay FAILED
Installing github.com/godoctor/godoctor FAILED

17 tools failed to install.

gocode:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode
go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "go.gopath".
For more details see: 'go help gopath'
go: GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "go.gopath".
For more details see: 'go help gopath'
```

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884965/gopath-error-in-windows-gopath-entry-is-relative-must-be-absolute-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GOPATH error in windows "GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884965/gopath-error-in-windows-gopath-entry-is-relative-must-be-absolute-path)